# Change the colors of objects that are within an array

Tags: ios, arrays, for-loop, uilabel

I'm trying to change the colors of my labels (objects of array) with this code:

```
-(void)setupObjectsWelcomeView
{
    NSArray *arrayColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_firstLabelWelcomeView, _secondLabelWelcomeView, _secondButtonWelcomeView, nil];

    for (NSString *labelText in arrayColors) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.text = labelText;
        label.textColor = [UIColor myMainColor];

    }
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What's in the array? `UILabel` references or `NSString` references?

Comment: And you do realize that you create new labels, set them up, but then don't use them in any way.

Comment: wow, have a button also

Comment: yeah, I've find the error, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array really has `UILabel` references, then you need:

```
for (UILabel *label in arrayColors) {
    label.textColor = [UIColor myMainColor];
}
```

This assume you only have label references in the array.

The code you posted assumed the values in the array were strings and you were creating new labels instead of updating the existing labels.